# SMTP email errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp

We just had our Rails app spit an error when ActionMailer was trying to send an email:

`Net::SMTPServerBusy - 451 Error while writing spool file`

We're using our own SMTP mailservers to send. Anyone know the details on this and how we can avoid it happening again in the future or if its possible to make ActionMailer try to send the email a few times if an error occurs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code and the description of the error states that this is an error on the mail server.

I suggest you check the mail servers to pinpoint the error (probably out of disk space or something similar).

When it comes to ActionMailer it is supposed to raise an exception if the configuration parameter `raise_delivery_errors` is set (default in Production but not in Development I believe), so you can check that one and try to resend if it triggers.